# Displaying brackets inside curly brackets in react JSX

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which has the following -

```
{tree[treeType].count > 0 ? tree[treeType].count : null}
```

The aim of it is to show the count only when count is greater than 0 but **it should be shown inside () these brackets** If the count is 0 nothing should be shown

I have tried to go with - `({tree[treeType].count > 0 ? tree[treeType].count : null})` but this shows brackets no matter what and also this - `{tree[treeType].count > 0 ? (tree[treeType].count) : null}` but this gives error.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tree[treeType].count > 0 ? `(${tree[treeType].count})` : null
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use this code:

```
{tree[treeType].count > 0 ? '(' + tree[treeType].count + ')' : null}
```